# Cross compiling c application library referring other libraries symbolically linked

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling, arm-linux

I am trying to build an application(libnodeapplication) which is dependent on a shared library(libnode.so) which in turn depends on another shared library(libgentoo-5.so.100) which I have pasted at the same location as the libnode(inside /usr/lib/)

Problem is second dependent library is symbolically linked to another file

what changes are needed in the compile command to build it successfully(for symbolically linkd files refrened in the shared library)

I tried with  -Wl,-rpath=<path to usr/lib/path_to_libgentoo-5.so.100 (also without file name) as well :

**command2 :**

```
gcc main.o -o libnodeapplication -L/usr/lib/-lnode -Wl,-rpath=/usr/lib/
```

**error**

below is the error

```
ld: warning: libgentoo-5.so.100, needed by /usr/lib/libnode.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
usr/lib/libnode.so: undefined reference to `symbol1 in libgentoo-5.so.100'
usr/lib/libnode.so: undefined reference to `symbol2 in libgentoo-5.so.100'
usr/lib/libnode.so: undefined reference to `symbol3 in libgentoo-5.so.100'
.
.
.
and so on
```

(for simplicity i have used gcc instead of arm linux cross compiler)
so my end application is libnodeapplication which depends on shared lib => libnode.so

libnode.so is being built using the libgentoo-5.so.100 (which is present in the /usr/lib and symbolically linked to libgentoo-5.so.100.20.0 : libgentoo-5.so.100 -> libgentoo-5.so.100.20.0)

I use this **command1** :

`gcc obj1.o obj2.o obj3.o -shared -o libnode.so /usr/lib/libgentoo-5.so.100`

When i try to use the objdum -t libnode.so , I can find all those symbols which are reported as undefined symbols when I try to build the libnodeapplication by above **command2**

**My Makefile(for libnodeapplication)**

```
CC=<path to tool chain>arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
LIB_NAME=-lnode
LIBS=-L$(TARGET_DIR)/usr/lib
INCS=-I./include/

OBJS=libnodeapplication.o

libnodeapplication: $(OBJS)
            $(CC) $(OBJS) -o libnodeapplication $(LIBS) $(LIB_NAME)

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) $(INCS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    -rm -rf *.o libnodeapplication
    -rm -rf $(TARGET_DIR)/root/libnodeapplication

install:
    cp libnodeapplication $(TARGET_DIR)/root
    chmod +x $(TARGET_DIR)/root/libnodeapplication
```

**Make file for libnode.so**

```
CC=<path to tool chain>arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -fPIC
INCS=-I./include/
LIBS=$(TARGET_DIR)/usr/lib/libgentoo-5.so.100
OBJS=libnode.o helper.o

libnode: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(OBJS) -shared -o a.so $(LIBS)

libnode.o: libnode.c
        $(CC) $(INCS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@     

helper.o: helper.c
        $(CC) $(INCS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
        -rm -rf *.o 
        -rm -rf libnode.so
        -rm -rf $(TARGET_DIR)/usr/lib/libnode.so
        -rm -rf $(TARGET_DIR)/usr/include/libnode.h

install:
        -cp libnode.so $(TARGET_DIR)/usr/lib
        -cp libnode.h $(TARGET_DIR)/usr/include
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to link against symbolic links.
The problem here is that the linker is trying to resolve all the references, so it needs libgentoo-5.so.100. If you have already used libgentoo-5.so.100 when generating libnode.so, you can add `-Wl,-rpath-link=path_to_libgentoo` (which is the same as the path for libnode) and it will work.
An other solution could be to also use libgentoo-5.so.100 when linking the executable. with `-l` and `-L` options.

there is a minimaliste exemple:

```
all:exec

libx:
    cd xf; \
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -c $(CFLAGS) -fpic  x.c -I.;\
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -shared -o libx.so x.o;\
    ln -s libx.so libx.so.10;\

liby:libx
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -c $(CFLAGS) -fpic y.c -I. -I./xf
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -shared -o liby.so y.o /home/youssef/test/arm2/xf/libx.so.10

exec:liby
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc $(CFLAGS) -o exec z.c -I. -I./xf -L. -ly -Wl,-rpath=./xf
```

the folder xf contain x.c ( which contain one function ) and x.h.
y.c contain one function which call the function in x.c.
z.c contain one function which call the function in y.c.

This example compile well with `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0`

Comment: Thaks, but same error. please see the post above . I have updated

Comment: path_to_libgentoo-5.so.100 must not be present in the path. could you give the exact command line you are using?

Comment: updated with some cleaner commands and logs

Comment: I added an example .can you try it to confirm if it is working or not in your machine. it iw working well on mine.

Comment: I paste my Make file , can you please suggest the necessary chages.

Comment: I tried your Makefile with some modifications. set $(TARGET_DIR)=$(Home)/test/raulp . all the source files are in this folder except header files which are in the folder include , and i added a rule to generate a libgentoo.so and create a symlinlk . And it worked well. did you tried the example i suggested ? are you sure all the tools are working well? are you sure libgentoo.so contains all the needed symbols?

Comment: yes i tried and same result. I see the difference in your make file.You are generating the dependent .so (libx.so.10 , equivalent to my libgentoo) using source code.In my csae i dont have source files but the .so installed in usr/lib. second I ntoiced using the objdump -t libgentoo and i cant find any symbolks , it says no symbols but with -T(dynamic option) i got all the symbols.

Comment: and the unreferenced symbols are the ones which has *UND* written infront of them like this : 00000000         *UND* 00000000              messagehdr_symbol

Comment: You are not seeing anything with the -t option because the library was striped. it is normal in libnode you find UND for the missing symbols.Can you confirm the libgentoo are really containing the code of the undefined symbols from libnode? At this point i think the problem is coming from libgentoo.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine, but I noticed you forgot the -L flag in the Makefile for libnode

```
LIBS=$(TARGET_DIR)/usr/lib/libgentoo-5.so.100
=>
LIBS=-L$(TARGET_DIR)/usr/lib/libgentoo-5.so.100
```

Also when linking you usually don't have to specify the full path/name of your library, Usually you would go only with the flag
`-lgentoo` The reason is the compiler will look in $PATH for a suitable library that will be named 'libgentoo.so' wich will be a sym link to whatever version is currently used on your system, for example

```
$ls /usr/lib/libgentoo*
/usr/lib/libgentoo.so -> /usr/lib/libgentoo-5.so
/usr/lib/libgentoo-5.so -> /usr/lib/libgentoo-5.so.100
/usr/lib/libgentoo-5.so.100
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **command1** was right - you just have to use the same way in **command2**: name the library directly.

**command2:** `gcc main.o -o libnodeapplication /usr/lib/node.so`

Full working example:

```
$ cat b.c     # (= libgentoo)
int b(int x) {
        return x%4;
}

$ cat a.c     # (= libnode)
int b(int);
int a(int x) {
        return b(x+3);
}

$ cat main.c  # (= nodeapplication)
int a(int);
int main() {
        return a(2);
}

$ pwd
/mounts/compilepartition/a-b-main/
$ mkdir -p ../toomuch  # (Just for fun)
$ gcc -shared -o b.so b.c
$ gcc a.c -shared -o a.so $PWD/b.so
$ gcc main.c -o app /mounts/compilepartition/toomuch/../a-b-main/a.so
$ ldd app
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7...)
    /mounts/compilepartition/toomuch/../a-b-main/a.so (0xf7...)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7...)
    /mounts/compilepartition/a-b-main/b.so (0xf7...)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x56...)
$ ./app; echo $?
1
$
```

**Tip**: For cross compiling, you can *hide* your build path, e.g. with

`gcc a.c -shared -o a.so -L /my/complex/build/path -l:b.so`

- Link-time path `/my/complex/build/path/b.so`
- Run-time path ??? -> must be found at runtime

**Tip**: For cross compiling, you can *replace* your build path, e.g. with

`gcc a.c -shared -o a.so -L /my/complex/build/path -l:b.so -W,-rpath=/usr/lib`

- Link-time path `/my/complex/build/path/b.so`
- Run-time path `/usr/lib/b.so`

(OK, it's no replacement, you're just adding a hint. Maybe you will actually get a different `b.so`)

**Tip**: For runtime searching relative to the object/executable, use `'$ORIGIN'` (quoted in single quotes! (in GNU/Linux or GNU/*, probably even in Windows))

`gcc a.c -shared -o a.so -L /my/complex/build/path -l:b.so -W,-rpath='$ORIGIN'/sub`

- Link-time path `/my/complex/build/path/a.so`
- Link-time path `/my/complex/build/path/b.so`
- Run-time path `/usr/lib/a.so` (for instance)
- Run-time path `/usr/lib/sub/b.so`

(Warning: this gets complicated because you may need to store the sub-sub-libraries in the required relative path *at link-time* for linking e.g. a final executable.)

**Tip**: You can look on shared objects' and final executables' load dependencies with `ldd ./a.so` or `ldd ./app` (host=target). If host!=target use `strings ./a.so` or `strings ./app` -> here you see "b.so"/"a.so" and "/usr/lib", amongst lots of cryptic stuff.